# Is it OK to pass a lot of props to a child component (redux)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-props

I have a component that has a child component within it.

This child component needs to access to the state, and dispatch a lot of actions. So I ended up having a component that takes all these properties through his own props.

```
render(){
   const menu = <Menu
            navigator={navigator}
            userTracks={this.props.tracks}
            currentTrackID={this.props.currentTrack.id}
            onAddNewTrack={() => {this.props.addNewTrack()}}
            onEditTrack={(track) => {this.props.onEditTrack(track)}}
            onClearBeacons={(track) => {this.props.onClearBeacons(track)}}
            onDeleteTrack={(track) => {this.props.onDeleteTrack(track)}}/>;

        return(
            <SideMenu
                menu={menu}
                isOpen={this.props.sideMenuOpened}
                onChange={(state) => {this.props.changeSideMenuOpened(state)}}
                menuPosition='right'>
                ...more stuff...
            </SideMenu>
        );
```

I rely a lot on this component, and it is highly probable that the list of props will keep on growing again and again.

**Is there any cleaner way to access the store in a child component other than through props  ?
Is it okay to do it this way ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the code in the following manner:

```
onClick(type, data) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'addNewTrack':
            this.props.addNewTrack();
            break;

        case 'editTrack':
            this.props.onEditTrack(data.track);
            break;

        case 'clearBeacons':
            this.props.onClearBeacons(data.track);
            break;

        case 'deleteTrack':
            this.props.onDeleteTrack(data.track);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}


render() {
    const menuProps = {
        navigator: navigator,
        userTracks: this.props.tracks,
        currentTrackID: this.props.currentTrack.id,
        onClick: this.onClick
    }
    const menu = <Menu {...menuProps} />

    return (
        <SideMenu
            menu={menu}
            isOpen={this.props.sideMenuOpened}
            onChange={(state) => { this.props.changeSideMenuOpened(state) }}
            menuPosition='right'>
            ...more stuff...
            </SideMenu>
    );
}
```

As you can see the data props are combined as an object and spread onto the `<Menu />` component. For the multiple methods, I am only passing a single click. Menu component will send the `type` and `data` that each represents the various clicks.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Great ! That seems to be a very clean way to do it, thanks for the idea !